# Python C Extension passing arguments by reference

Tags: python, python-c-extension

I am trying to write a python C wrapper for a function (libFunc) whose prototype is

```
libFunc(char**, int*, char*, int)
```

How do I use PyArg_ParseTuple for setting up the arguments for function call. Here is what I currently have

```
#include <Python.h>

    PyObject* libFunc_py(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
    {
        char* input;
        char** output;
        int inputlen;
        int* outputlen;

        PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "sisi" , output, outputlen, &input, &inputlen);


        int ret = libFunc(output, outlen, input, inputlen);


        return Py_BuildValue("i", ret);
    }
```

I am able to do the same with ctypes using byref.

Comment: Here's an example that uses [Cython](http://cython.org): [libfunc.pyx](https://gist.github.com/cf5e036a88d1b12ea64a)

Comment: Thanks for the code..but I don't have pyrex in my environment. Can you tell me, how to free the memory(allocated by libfunc) in my code below?

Comment: 1. Users of your code don't need Cython. You only need it to generate C sources for you. 2. You could call `free(output)` if `libFunc()` uses `malloc()` to allocate memory for `output`. 3. s/outlen/outputlen/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing it this way

```
#include <Python.h>

    PyObject* libFunc_py(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
    {
        char* input;
        char* output;
        int inputlen;
        int outputlen;

        PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "s#" , &input, &inputlen);


        int ret = libFunc(&output, &outlen, input, inputlen);

        if (ret !=0)
        {
            Py_ErrSetString(PyExc_RunTimeError, "ErrorMessage");
            return NULL;
        }

        PyObject* retStr =  Py_BuildValue("s#", output,outputlen);

        if(output)
           free(output)

        return retStr;
    }
```

Comment: 1. `if(!PyArg_ParseTuple(...)) return NULL;` 2. You could use [`{ PyErr_SetString(PyExc_RuntimeError, "Error message"); return NULL; }`](http://www.google.com/codesearch#search/&q=PyErr_SetString\%28PyExc_RuntimeError&type=cs) instead of `return Py_BuildValue("s#", "Error", 5)`.